# How can I list up orphan packages in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project with several outdated dependencies.

One of the dependencies is just listed up in composer.lock

I removed every package from composer.json with

```
composer remove <package>
```

but the package is still listed in composer.lock. So it seems that this is an orphan package.

If use

```
composer depends <package>
```

it returns "could not find package"

- Is it safe to remove the package?
- Is there a command to check for orphan packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just removed the package.

I checked if the package was used in the source with grep

```
grep -rnwi vendor/ -e "namespace"
```

As the the package was listed in the dev section, I run

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Then I removed the packages from the composer.lock

and run

```
composer install
```

The package was not installed again